# Overflow:auto is disabling pinch and zoom - How to keep pinch and zoom enabled

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css

I am creating a site with fixed header and fixed footer and sidebar. So there is only smaller area that I want scrolling.

To get the scrollbar to only apply to the scrollable area rather than the whole page, I have used the obvious overflow:auto on the content area div.

```
#content {
height:100% 
width:100%;
background:yellow;
overflow:auto; 
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

}

The only problem I have is that when I have overflow:auto in the css it disables the pinch and zoom on the ipad. I need to add I am using the overflow:auto to enable a scroll on that div to prevent the "ios bounce" on the fixed elements.

Is there a way I can get the pinch and zoom working again whilst still having this overflow content div area?

Comment: Could you add your html and css to http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: Here is the http://jsfiddle.net/W7Q5N/2/